# What is the maximum thrust a pressure-fed methalox engine can produce?

Tags: spacex, the-moon, crewed-spaceflight, landing

SpaceX revealed on 4/30/2020 a new version of Starship designed to land humans on the Moon. Auxiliary engines are mounted high on the body for the last part of the descent, apparently to eliminate the problem of the powerful Raptor engine kicking up dangerous amounts of regolith.

I understand pressure-fed engines are limited by the propellant tank pressure; for Starship it is 6 bar. It’s very difficult to estimate from an artist’s rendering, but for a working number assume a bell diameter of 0.5 meters. The Isp in a vacuum may also be useful.

Extra info for the curious: Starship will use autogenous pressurization of its propellant tanks, and is planned to use hot gas thrusters for RCS. A pressure-fed engine is an obvious candidate for the auxiliary landing thrusters, and I’m wondering how powerful one can be. From other SpaceX info we know the Raptors will decelerate the ship to zero vertical velocity at *x* height above the lunar surface; the ship will then drop, relying on auxiliary thrusters to minimize the fall rate. The lunar design shows special landing legs, apparently enhanced for shock absorption. The design has been chosen for development by NASA for their human lunar lander program.

I asked a similar question 4 months ago, but this new information makes the question much more concrete.

Comment: Pressure-fed engine's efficiency (specific impulse) is limited by tank pressure (chamber pressure), not thrust. You can have as much thrust you want simply by having a big engine and burn fuel super fast.

Comment: The tank pressure is 6 bar, so that is the upper limit for the Isp. I'm looking for actual numbers here, that's what I most need help with.

Comment: Musk described the Starship's attitude control thrusters as being fed by "High pressure CH4 bottle, high pressure O2 bottle," Meaning gaseous tanks, no liquid. The main tanks are liquid, so this means they do not get fuel directly from the main tanks. So the tanks that feed these are probably higher pressure than 6 bar. (Clearly pumps and heaters could be used to top off the gaseous tanks from the main tanks.)